# Out of stack space exception

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, xrm

I am working in CRM 2013 where i need to set a date of my textbox and save it to CRM 2013 database.

look at my code :

> var CRMForm = document.parentWindow.parent.Xrm.Page;
>
> var currentDateTime = new Date();
>
> CRMForm.getAttribute("date").setValue(currentDateTime);

But i am getting an exception here : Out of stack space

Comment: When is that javascript being executed?  When is the error occuring?

Comment: You likely have an infinite loop where your code logic is causing a change that triggers that code to run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution myself and its as following :

```
var dt= CRMForm.getAttribute("date");

if(dt.getValue() != null)

{

dt.setValue(dt.getValue().setFullYear(currentDateTime.getFullYear()));

dt.setValue(dt.getValue().setDate(currentDateTime.getDate()));

dt.setValue(dt.getValue().setMonth(currentDateTime.getMonth()));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a form or on a custom Web resource?

I'm getting confused because you are getting the parent form,

```
var currentDateTime = new Date();
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("requestdeliveryby").setValue(currentDateTime);
```

This should be more than enough. Remember that you need to register it properly when you edit the form:

Properties->Events->OnLoad ? Looking at your example looks like you are trying to get the Xrm namespace from the wrong form.